# Can`t connect to MongoDB Server on Mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, server

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.16
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-02-08T22:30:51.573-0500 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

This message appear to me and sincerely I don't know what to do.

I tried with "**mongo**" and appear *-bash: mongod: command not found*

I tried with "**mongod**" and appear *-bash: mongod: command not found*

I tried with "**brew services list**" and appear *-bash: brew: command not found*

I tried a lot of things from internet and nothing work on OS CATALINA.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

**homebrew** creates symbolic links to all the programs it installs. It creates them in the directory `/usr/local/bin`. So, if you want to use **homebrew**, or anything it has installed, you need to set your PATH to include that directory:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Ideally, you would do that in your login script (probably `$HOME/.bash_profile`) so that it is set every time you login. Ensure you do **not** have a space either side of the equals sign (`=`).

The fact that you get an error message saying *"brew command not found"* suggests your PATH doesn't currently include `/usr/local/bin`.